# problem while installng teamviewer?

Tags: teamviewer

While I start installing teamviewer, I got this error message....

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 640770 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing teamviewer-monitoring (1.0.160092) ...
rm: cannot remove '/var/opt/teamviewer-rm/*.json': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package teamviewer-monitoring (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer-monitoring
Error in function:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove problematic package on low level

```
sudo dpkg --purge teamviewer-monitoring
```

and resume package operations with

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. When I entered the first command: it is showing error. The eror message is:  root@Hari:/home/hari# sudo dpkg --purge teamviewer-monitoring
(Reading database ... 641270 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing teamviewer-monitoring (1.0.160092) ...
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/opt/teamviewer-rm/*.json’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package teamviewer-monitoring (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer-monitoring

Comment: Use `sudo mkdir -p /var/opt/teamviewer-rm/`, `sudo touch /var/opt/teamviewer-rm/temp.json` and then retry.